# Web.config: Allow all users on given path at machine level

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config

I have successfully setup [Elmah](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) at machine level in order to have error logging for all web applications. Now I want to add the RSS feed of each application to Outlook. Problem is applications are secured and won't allow Outlook to access RSS feed (at my.web.application.com/elmah.axd/rss). Since I can't ask Outlook to login in the app, I figured I'd give access to anybody to the elmah path and restrict by IP address (actually restricting to our local network), with the following config:

```
<location path="elmah.axd">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
                <clear/>
                <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true" />
                <add ipAddress="10.0.0.0" allowed="true" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" />
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

This actually works when put in the application's Web.config: I have access to the elmah.axd page without logging in. Perfect. Now I wanted to do this at machine level so every application behaves the same. So I put it at the same places I put the Elmah config, that is:

- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config
- C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config (IIS config)

Although putting the config there made Elmah respond on every web application, it doesn't work with that security config: the applications still ask to login... What need I do to make it work at machine level ?

Would it be that in machine level web.config the path is not relative to the applications ? but then how can I make it work ? (I also tried ~/elmah.axd without success...)

Answer (score 0):

Check for overrides in each application's configuration.

> The local configuration settings override settings in parent
>   configuration files.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: Indeed I have a <deny users="?"> in each application in order to allow only logged in users, but the <allow users="*" /> in the machine level config is for the <location path="elmah.axd"> and there isn't any application that has config for that elmah.axd path, which could override it.

Comment: You might have to enter the absolute path in the machine config. Quote from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648667.aspx : With Machine.config, if you specify the path, it must be fully qualified and include the Web site name, virtual directory name, and optionally, a subdirectory and file name.

Comment: If that's the case, it would make it impossible to apply the config to all web applications in a generic manner. I'll try it anyway to see if it works... (actually, I didn't use the Machine.config, but rather the machine global Web.config)

Comment: Well, you are right, it actually works that way. When I include the web application name, it works! Unfortunately, that's rather annoying in my case because now I can't write generic config code...